# Composite with label aligned left and buttons right

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I work on an Eclipse plug-in and at a moment in time a pop-up is shown. Inside the pop-up dialog box, I want to create an area where I have a label on the left and two buttons alligned right.

```java
public void createBottom(Composite parent) {
    Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.FILL | SWT.WRAP | SWT.BORDER);
    GridData gridData = new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, false);
    composite.setLayoutData(gridData);
    composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, false));

    addLabel(composite);
    addButton1(composite);
    addButton2(composite);
}
```

Currently the result looks like this:
 [image: this]

While I'm expecting something more like this:
[image]

How can I possibly align the `Label` on the left and the two buttons on the right?

Comment: What are `addLabel`, `addButton1` and `addButton2`?

Comment: @greg-449 Aren't they suggestive? The 3 methods add the 3 items. `addLabel` adds `Test`, `addButton1` adds the `Ok` button and `addButton2` adds the `Close` button.

Comment: "Suggestions" are no good. you need to show us a proper [mcve] leaving out chunks of code just makes it more difficult to respond.

Comment: @greg-449 My apologies, fair enough, I'll keep in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `SWT.FILL` and `SWT.WRAP` are **not** valid styles for `Composite`. The Javadoc for the control specifies which styles you can use.

Use something like:

```java
Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.BORDER);
GridData gridData = new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, false);
composite.setLayoutData(gridData);
composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, false));

Label label = new Label(composite, SWT.BEGINNING);
label.setText("Test");
label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));

Button but1 = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH);
but1.setText("OK");
but1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.END, SWT.CENTER, false, false));

Button but2 = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH);
but2.setText("Close");
but2.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.END, SWT.CENTER, false, false));
```

The layout data for the label grabs the extra space in the composite, and the buttons have end alignment.